# Me sale esto: System.Int32[] Al sumar los elementos de un vector c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Ando aprendiendo el uso de los constructores en c# hoy. Busco sumar todos los valores del vector para mostrar el resultado. Todo funciona pero al imprimir la suma de todos los elemento, lo que tengo de resultado es:

**La suma es System.Int32[]**

Estuve probando con suma.ToString, pero no funciona!

Como puedo hacer que se muestre el numero real???

```
using System;

namespace demo
{

    public class hello
    {
        private int[] numeros;
        private int [] suma;

        public hello()
        {
            numeros = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i+1 + ". Diga un numero: ");
                string linea = Console.ReadLine();
                numeros[i] = int.Parse(linea);
            }

            ClassSumador(numeros);
        }


        public void ClassSumador(int[] numeros)
        {
            suma = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
            {
                suma[i] += numeros[i];

            }

            Console.WriteLine("La suma es: " + suma);

        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            hello h = new hello();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el método `ClassSumador` recibe un arreglo de enteros, es de suponer que la suma de este arreglo sea un entero.

Es decir, si recibo:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

El resultado esperado sería

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21
```

El primer problema que tienes es que estás declarando el miembro de clase `suma` como un arreglo de enteros, cuando debiera ser un entero.

```
private int suma;
```

Luego, ya en el método `ClassSumador`, cambiar la inicialización por una asignación del valor 0

```
suma = 0;
```

Y finalmente proceder con la suma dentro del ciclo:

```
suma += numeros[i];
```

En el código actual, si `numeros` fuese un arreglo de más de 5 elementos, obtendrías un error.

Finalmente un par de comentarios que no tienen que ver con tu pregunta pero si con tu código:

- Considero que parte del arte de la programación consiste en mantener las cosas **consistentes y simples**, así es más fácil de entender el código que se lee.  Por eso mismo me provoca algo de *dolor de cabeza* ver que un método se llame `ClassLoQueSea`. Suelo recomendar que los nombres de métodos inicien siempre con un verbo (en infinitivo), pues el método representa, generalmente, una acción. También evitar utilizar como nombres de métodos palabras que representan otras cosas en la OOP o en el lenguaje. El nombre `ClassSuma` en un método, es más o menos el equivalente a tener un trozo de papel rojo que se llama `PapelAzul`, o un método llamado `DibujarCirculo`, que toca una canción por la bocina.
- También me produce algo de problema ver *spanglish* en el nombre del método.  Me parece mejor que podría llamarse `calcularSuma`, `sumarArreglo`, `calculateSum`, `sumArray` (si no imprimiera el valor), pero dado que lo imprime, también podría llamarse `imprimirSuma`, `mostrarSuma`, o similares.
- Finalmente, entiendo que la convención en `c#` es utilizar mayúscula inicial en el nombre de las clases y minúscula inicial en el nombre de los métodos (programo solo eventualmente en c#, así que no lo digo con autoridad, pero te sugiero investigarlo y seguir la norma.  El lenguaje funciona de todas formas si no la sigues, pero se hace más fácil que otras personas puedan leer y comprender tu código, así como se facilita leer el de otras personas cuando todos siguen este tipo de convenciones.

En código se vería algo como:

```
    public void calcularSumatoria(int[] numeros) {
        suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++) {
            suma += numeros[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("La suma es: " + suma);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por, primero explicarme lo que buscaba y de segundo plano, gracias por anadir tus recomendaciones para que el codigo que escriba cumpla con normas para que este sea facil de leer y comprender por otros programadores.